# Can't implement a class in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to implement an interface in VB6. I have defined the class `Cast_Speed` like this...

```
Public Function Run_Time() As Long

End Function
```

and the implementation like this...

```
Option Explicit
Implements Cast_Speed

Public Function Cast_Speed_Run_Time() As Long
    Cast_Speed_Run_Time = 0
End Function
```

but attempting to compile it gives 'object module needs to implement 'Run_Time' for interface 'Cast_Speed'. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? My subroutines seem to be quite all right, but all the functions I try have this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't like the underscore character in the method name. Try using `RunTime()` instead.

I just tested it without the underscore and it works fine for me:

```
'// class Cast_Speed
Option Explicit

Public Function RunTime() As Long

End Function


'// class Class1
Option Explicit

Implements Cast_Speed

Public Function Cast_Speed_RunTime() As Long
  Cast_Speed_RunTime = 0
End Function
```

Comment: thank you for that; it would never have occurred to me to try it.

Comment: +1 From the VB6 documentation *Creating Interfaces for Use With the Implements Statement* `Interface methods cannot have underscores in their names` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262287(VS.60).aspx

Comment: -1 because of the use of PUBLIC keyword when the Interface methods should be PRIVATE instead. This works but it is not good practice and doesn't make sense in order to achieve polymorphism in VB. See BobRode's answer.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Just make the CastSpeed_RunTime() function Private. This way, it is accessed through the CastSpeed interface: You declare a variable of type CastSpeed, then instanciate this variable as a new Class1 object. As you see, I have also avoided the underscore in the Clas name. VB convention is to use camelCase instead.

Comment: @onedaywhen: The point is that that's what an interface is.  An interface is a *definition* of a series of operations.  It is not an *implementer* of the operations; that's why they get implemented by another class.  In other words, an interface by definition compels the user to access methods of implementing classes through itself (although of course a class can both implement an interface and provide other methods that are not part of the interface). That's the "contract" that a class makes by representing itself as an implementer of the interface.  (...)

Comment: (...) So, if in a class definition a variable is declared Public, it can hold state data directly, and therefore the class is not an interface.  Therefore the OP's goal is by definition contradictory: he's both "trying to implement an interface" and hold state data in the interface.  He instead needs to hold the state data in an implementation of the interface, for the interface to be an interface.

Comment: If the OP declares it Public, it would then be an "abstract class."  An abstract class is a class that doesn't implement all of its operations.  An interface is a form of abstract class that doesn't implement *any* of its operations, so the term "abstract class" is generally used--not entirely accurately--to mean a class that implements *some but not all* of its operations.

Comment: Well, I've given you the point back, since you are right that your answer fixes the problem, but this "tangential design decision" is crucial to the subject of Polymorphism, which in VBA is achieved by the implementation of interfaces, and I think it is important to make it clear.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Now, I've made a test, and I must admit that making the members private is not so crucial as I just said. Polymorphism works the same, so you were right. The default in VBA is to make the members private while implementing interfaces, but it is not mandatory. This said, it is a great way to separate interfaces in objects and make programation more clear, so I still advise the use of the Private keyword.

Answer (score 5):

While you can make interface implementations public, it isn't considered good practice, any more than it is considered good practice to allow an interface to be directly instantiated as you also can do.  It is simply an example of the maxim that it is possible to write extremely bad code in VB6.  :)

Best practice is as follows:

1. Interface instancing property is PublicNotCreatable.
2. Implemented Interface Methods are scoped Private.

Thus:

```
Dim x as iMyInterface
Set x = new MyiMyInterfaceImplementation
x.CalliMyInterfaceMethodA
x.CalliMyInterfaceMethodY
```

And so on.  If someone attempts to directly instantiate the interface, that should cause an error, and if someone attempts to call an implemented method directly instead of polymorphically through the interface that should return an error too.

Comment: The reason that the interface is PublicNotCreatable is because you don't want to be able to create an instance of the interface. Rather, you declare variables as the type of the interface, and instantiate implementers of the interface.  The reason you want the methods to be scoped private is because you don't want to be able to call them directly.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, Interface Implementations in VB6 needed to be private (even though the interface declares them as public).

Try changing:

```
Public Function Cast_Speed_Run_Time() As Long
```

To:

```
Private Function Cast_Speed_Run_Time() As Long
```

You can also read up on [implementing interfaces in VB6 here](http://www.shomsky.com/Technical/Articles/ImplementingInterfacesInVB6.asp) (which seems to back me up).

Comment: @Justin Niessner - thank you for that; it has done the trick. I will study your reference.

Comment: Yes, you are mistaken. I just tested: it defaults to `Private` but manually editing the scope to `Public` works fine.

Comment: @onedaywhen - Editting the scope to public would change that from an interface implementation to a regular public function. Consider the change from Public to Private fixed the problem for the OP, I'm pretty sure I'm right.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: Try for yourself the working code I just posted to my answer ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen - I would, but unfortunately I haven't had a way to build VB6 code installed on my machine for years. :-P

Comment: @Justin Niessner: this is vanilla VBA so will work in Word, Excel, etc in case you have one of those. Excel is what I used myself! :)

Comment: @Justin Niessner - I was a little mistaken when I said that had fixed it; it had corrected another function, but I also needed onedaywhen's help below. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @Justin @onedaywhen Justin is wrong, onedaywhen is right. I just compiled onedaywhen's code with a public function in VB6. Also there's a topic in the VB6 docs that supports onedaywhen, see my comment on that answer

Comment: @onedaywhen: While it is true that you can do as you say, that doesn't mean that you should.  The point about interfaces is that they expose functionality to the public, while hiding the implementation details of that functionality.  You don't want people calling the implementer methods directly; instead they should call the Interface methods and access the implementer methods that way.

Comment: @BobRodes: "[interfaces] expose functionality to the public" -- what you are describing is more like an API. "You don't want people calling the implementer methods directly" -- [Let's say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165323(v=office.10).aspx) the architect created a `LibraryItem` interface with a `CheckedOut` (Boolean) property and I (not the general public!) am designing  `Book` class that implements `LibraryItem`. It is likely that I will want my class to have a public `CheckedOut` property anyhow, perhaps not with the same name...

Comment: @BobRodes: but I agree with you that I definitely don't want my public method to be named `LibraryItem_CheckedOut`. I would rather create my own `CheckedOut` public property to be called from `LibraryItem_CheckedOut` (which would remain private). But *requiring* users to cast a `Book` as a `LibraryItem` just to tests its `CheckedOut` state is overly restrictive. Note in C#, Java, etc the interface contract would require me to create a public property of the same name. The `<inteface>_<procname>` requirement is a quirk of VBA and not a welcome one.

Comment: The point about an interface is to create a common way to access related objects, and allow them to behave differently when accessed.  Your "LibraryItem" example is a good one, actually.  Let's use a "CheckOut" method instead of a "CheckedOut" property, because the method is more likely to vary from item to item than is the property, which is either yes or no.  The point is, all library items can be checked out, but there might be a different process to check out different items.

Comment: Books might get a stamp in the back, tapes might have other stuff done, and maybe rare books have to have someone check in every day or the library goon squad will come to the person's house and take the book.  The point is then that each library item will implement a "CheckOut" method in its own way.

Comment: Now, I disagree that the <interface>_<procname> requirement is entirely a quirk of VBA.  In C#, if you are explicitly implementing an interface, you have to provide an InterfaceName.PropertyName construct for each property of the interface that you implement.  It's the same restriction really.  Perhaps you are just saying that you don't like the syntax semantics, and you wouldn't get an argument from me there.

Comment: But the point is that you Dim a variable as type Interface, and set it = new Implementation.  Then, you call the interface's methods, and in turn the interface calls the underlying Interface_MethodName in the implementation class.  You can't call the implementer methods directly.  If you find that restrictive, well, that's polymorphism.  The restriction opens up opportunities that you wouldn't otherwise have.

Comment: An interesting analog to polymorphism in the manufacturing world is the plug to an electrical outlet.  This "ElectricalAppliance" interface is the same for a very wide range of appliances ("interface implementations").  If someone didn't like accessing the house current via the interface, they could certainly do so, but it's easier to use what's already in place.

Answer (score 1):

For a good overview of this subject, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260635(v=vs.60).aspx#ifacebased_vbifaces .